# Positioning form CSS

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a question regarding aligning the input fields in form using flexbox.
This is my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSSE6.png)

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.form input,
  select {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div className="form">
  <label>
    <span>Please write your title: </span>
    <select>
      <option value="male">Mr.</option>
      <option value="female">Mrs.</option>
      <option value="female-young">Miss.</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Please write your name: </span>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Please write your surname: </span>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Please pick today's date: </span>
    <input type="date" />
  </label>
</div>
```

I want to align input fields. Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to change is the span tag from span to div.
This will lead to the title taking up the entire screen and the input field being pushed to the new line, aligning all four of them. To make the input fields also inline, just wrap each input field along with the title inside a div as shown below(apologies for the bad formatting).

```
<div className="form">
<label>
<div>
<span>Please write your title: </span>
  <select>
  <option value="male">Mr.</option>
  <option value="female">Mrs.</option>
  <option value="female-young">Miss.</option>
  </select>
</div>
</label>
<label>
<div>
<span>Please write your name: </span>
<input type="text" />
</div>
</label>
<label>
<div>
<span>Please write your surname: </span>
<input type="text" />
</div>
</label>
<label>
<div>
<span>Please pick today's date: </span>
<input type="date" />
</div>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I want input fields to be inline with the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Grid could help here.

example from your code.

```css
.form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(2,auto);
  gap:0.5em;
  justify-content:start;
}

label {
display:contents;
}
.form input,
  select {
  margin:auto;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <label>
    <span>Please write your title: </span>
    <select>
      <option value="male">Mr.</option>
      <option value="female">Mrs.</option>
      <option value="female-young">Miss.</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Please write your name: </span>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Please write your surname: </span>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Please pick today's date: </span>
    <input type="date" />
  </label>
</div>
```

`label{display:contents}` can be avoided if you **do not wrap the input or select inside the label** , but link it via the attribute `for`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/labelto get the purpose and usage ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I want to use flexbox.

Comment: @user18389673 why not, it really is up to you, grid is for a 3d grid, flex for a 2d grid ;) *Take a look at the link about the label element (even if you do not want to modify this, you might think otherwise for your next project ;) )*

Answer (score 0):

I added a few more styles to your sample code if this is what you're looking for.

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.form label {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form label span {
  flex: 0 1 28%;
}
.form label input, .form label select {
  flex: 0 1 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <label>
    <span>Please write your title: </span>
    <select>
      <option value="male">Mr.</option>
      <option value="female">Mrs.</option>
      <option value="female-young">Miss.</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Please write your name: </span>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Please write your surname: </span>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Please pick today's date: </span>
    <input type="date" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, it didn't solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need flexbox here. Just define the `label` elements as `display: block` (to fill the entire line)  and the `span`s inside them as inline-blocks with a `min-width` setting that you adjust to the length of the longest span text:

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

label>span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div className="form">
  <label>
    <span>Please write your title: </span>
    <select>
      <option value="male">Mr.</option>
      <option value="female">Mrs.</option>
      <option value="female-young">Miss.</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Please write your name: </span>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Please write your surname: </span>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Please pick today's date: </span>
    <input type="date" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that too, but it also didn't work. I added text-align: start because I want labels to be on the left side.

Comment: note that I erased the flexbox from the container in my snippet

Answer (score 0):

After a day of trying, I figured out the solution.

```
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: start;
 }

span {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
}

input,
select {
 align-items: center;
}
```

Maybe not the best solution, but it got the job done.
Thanks everyone for help.